# Consume wsdl service using cfx:proxy-client in Mule ESB 3.3 - Could not find definition for service

Tags: mule

I am attempting to consume a wsdl service using cfx:proxy-client in Mule ESB 3.3 but keep getting this error

```
org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Could not find definition for service {http://support.cxf.module.mule.org/}ProxyService.
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.create(WSDLServiceFactory.java:139)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromWSDL(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:383)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:506)
```

Below is my simple flow:

```
<flow name="spider-middleware" doc:name="spider-middleware">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="salesforce" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <cxf:proxy-client operation="getCustomerByID"
                      payload="body"
                      wsdlLocation="http://localhost:4546/eplus-ws-fake/services/EplusCustomer/v1?wsdl"
                      enableMuleSoapHeaders="true"
                      doc:name="SOAP"/>
</flow>
```

The service is hardcoded to return a customer for getCustomerByID(1).
Please shed some lights on how do I get around the issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I got it working but only by providing a full SOAP envelope and not just the body, ie. using `payload="envelope"`.

Also I removed the `operation` and `wsdlLocation` attributes, which are useless for the `proxy-client`. I also had to add `SOAPAction` and `Content-Type` properties, otherwise the test webservice I'm using chokes on the request.

This gives (using a test service from WebServiceX.net):

```
<flow name="pureCxfProxyClient">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="test.in"
        exchange-pattern="request-response" />
    <set-property propertyName="SOAPAction"
        value="http://www.webservicex.net/getACHByZipCode" />
    <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="text/xml" />
    <http:outbound-endpoint address="http://www.webservicex.net/FedACH.asmx"
        exchange-pattern="request-response" >
        <cxf:proxy-client payload="envelope" />
    </http:outbound-endpoint>
</flow>
```

Note I used a VM endpoint, which allowed me to deal with the `XMLStreamReader` returned by the `cxf:proxy-client`.

In particular, I needed to do the following:

```
    final XMLStreamReader xsr = (XMLStreamReader) result.getPayload();
    xsr.nextTag();
```

to avoid crazy NPEs in `org.mule.module.xml.stax.ReversibleXMLStreamReader`.

All in all this is pretty intense... plus the `cxf:proxy-client` doesn't deliver much value when used standalone. You could actually just go with:

```
<flow name="pureCxfProxyClient">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="test.in"
        exchange-pattern="request-response" />
    <set-property propertyName="SOAPAction"
        value="http://www.webservicex.net/getACHByZipCode" />
    <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="text/xml" />
    <http:outbound-endpoint address="http://www.webservicex.net/FedACH.asmx"
        exchange-pattern="request-response" />
</flow>
```

... and be freed of the `XMLStreamReader` part.